# In wire grid polarisers, why does the incident wave cancel the reradiated wave in the forward direction?

Tags: optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light

I read this from Optics (Global Edition) by Eugene Hecht Page 347, Chapter 8: Polarisation. The author says that this is obvious but I seem to be missing something here. Is the incident wave out of phase with the wave propagating in the forward direction?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I suspect you are correct, but it would be helpful if you could post a diagram of the system so we know exactly what the configuration is, wavelengths, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Because for a good metal, the current is essentially 90$^\circ$ out of phase with the exciting radiation. This is due to the metal’s conductivity, which is largely imaginary. Then the re-radiated fields have another ~90$^\circ$ phase shift, bringing them (nearly) completely out of phase with the exciting radiation. Transmitted light is cancelled, and the emitted reflection sets up a standing wave on the incident side of the polarizer (with a *node* at the plane of the wires).